# Debug kernel booting to blank screen

Tags: linux, kernel, debug

I have a machine which works fine with the precompiled 'generic' ubuntu kernel (3.0.0-13) but when I try to boot up the precompiled 'virtual' ubuntu kernel (3.0.0-13) it just puts me on a blank screen and I can't see any output.

- What are the steps that I should take to get more information to be able to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about Ubuntu packages nomenclature, but aren't you perhaps trying to run a virtual-environment-only kernel on a physical machine?

Why do you want to use the "virtual" kernel?

As for regular debugging of the kernel: netconsole and COM1 are the common solutions.

Comment: You are right, the 'virtual' kernel flavour is mean to be run only inside a virtual machine, not on hardware. So that means that I'm probably missing critical drivers and that's why it is failing.